# Run a remote script on a remote node

Tags: ansible

Easy question.

I have a Python3 script on my remote node in the path `~/setup/inventory.py`, and I am trying to execute it remotly.
So I took a look at the `script` resource, which is searching on my local machine for the script.

How do I get Ansible to run my **remote** Python3 script. Executing it normally would look like os `python3 /setup/inventory.py ansible vscode bash`

Answer (score 0):

Use `command` or `shell` modules, depending on your case.

Something like

```
- name: execute my script
  command: python3 /setup/inventory.py ansible vscode bash
```